# Why format DATE_RFC7231 ignores timezones?

Tags: php, datetime

I was playing recently with date formats in PHP and the hardcoded `GMT` timezone in format `DATE_RFC7231` puzzles me.

I have example below of two the same dates formatted differently, however even if the input is the same, the output differs because of the timezone difference! So, the hours are not casted proportionaly to the given timezone and it displays confusing results.

```
echo DateTime::createFromFormat(DATE_ATOM, '2023-02-15T06:44:41+08:00')->format(DATE_ATOM); //2023-02-15T06:44:41+08:00
echo DateTime::createFromFormat(DATE_ATOM, '2023-02-15T06:44:41+08:00')->format(DATE_RFC7231); //Wed, 15 Feb 2023 06:44:41 GMT
```

Is this intentional to show always `GMT` despite the timezone set to the Datetime object? Or am I missing something essential about the format RFC7231?

Comment: Because it is defined as a GMT timezone - The Manual - _RFC 7231 (since PHP 7.0.19 and 7.1.5) (example: Sat, 30 Apr 2016 17:52:13 GMT)_

Comment: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.1.1

Answer (score 1):

Actually, now that I look at it it's generating `06:44:41+08:00` and `06:44:41 GMT` from the same input. Which is somewhat wrong-ish.

What is *actually* wrong, though, is thinking that a format string would perform a transformation on the DateTime object. The constant `DATE_RFC7231` is simply the string `"D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T"` which hard-codes the string `GMT` into the format.

The solution is to set the timezone to GMT before formatting, as below:

```php
var_dump(
    DateTime::createFromFormat(DATE_ATOM, '2023-02-15T06:44:41+08:00')->
        setTimezone(new DateTimezone('GMT'))->
        format(DATE_RFC7231)
);
```

Output:

```
string(29) "Tue, 14 Feb 2023 22:44:41 GMT"
```